# change forms.py widget dynamically with user input from dropdown field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, ace-editor

I am trying to make a coding webapp in which users can write choose language and write the code.For it I am using ace editor.Ace editor requires the "mode" variable to know the language and provide syntax highlighting.

So,I have made a dropdown and I want to set the value of "mode" as the value of the dropdown field.e.g. If the users choose C++ I want mode="c++".I have the following code but I can't think of how to do it.

- forms.py

  ```
  from django_ace import AceWidget

  class notepadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
      Your_code = forms.CharField(widget=AceWidget(mode='python', theme='clouds'))
      class Meta:
      model=notepadForm
      fields=['Title','Your_code','Separator']
  ```
- models.py

  ```
  class notepadForm(models.Model):
      CHOICES=[('python','Python'),('Cplusplus','C++'),('c','C')]

      Title=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=False,blank=False)
      Separator=models.CharField(choices=CHOICES,max_length=10,default=";")
      Your_code=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
  ```

I have searched for it and found some examples to dynamically add fields but modifying the widget I didn't found thats why I asked it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create dropdown using javascript and the modelist extension from ace

```html
<script src=http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js></script>
<script src=http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ext-modelist.js></script>
<script>
  var modelist = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist")
  var dom = ace.require("ace/lib/dom")
 
  // using buildDom from ace, but any other method of constructing dom can be used here
  var modePicker = dom.buildDom(["select", {
     value: "ace/mode/text",
      onchange: function() {
        editor.setOption("mode", this.value);
      }
    }, modelist.modes.map(function(x) {
      return ["option", {
        value: x.mode
      }, x.caption];
    })

  ], document.body);

  var editor = ace.edit(null, {
    maxLines: 10,
    minLines: 5
  })
  document.body.appendChild(editor.container)
</script>
```